# How do I make a persistent hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I would like a persistent hash; an object that act as a hash, but that can persist between program runs.

Ideally, it would only load in memory the value that are accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sdbm

```
require 'sdbm'

SDBM.open("/mypath/myfile.dbm") do |myMap|
    [...]

    myMap[key] = avalue

    [...]

    myvar = myMap[anotherKey]

    [...]
end
```

create to files : myfile.dbm.dir and myfile.dbm.pag

Answer (score 2):

Since persistent key/value storage is kind of everyones requirement, as it happens there are a large number of solutions.

[YAML](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/index.html) is probably the easiest way to persist Ruby objects.

[JSON](http://flori.github.com/json/) works as well but doesn't directly handle symbols.

MySQL and other SQL databases such as sqlite3 also solve this problem, of course. Usually, access is encapsulated within the [ActiveRecord ORM library](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/).

The Ruby core has a [Marshaling library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Marshal.html).

Comment: The question is not just to marshal object, it is to have something that can be access quicker that marshaling the full hash.  I know it exist in Perl, so I would expect it exist in Ruby.

Comment: Ahh, you mean, dbm?  Like dbmopen, etc?

Comment: [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) would be a nice and simple solution. Instead of storing as a hash, just create a simple schema mapping the object to the table. It's fast, especially if you're trying to store or search through hundreds or thousands of records.

Comment: @Guillaume What do you have in mind from Perl (`Storable`)? It may help people to understand what you want in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using [redis-rb](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb), which has a hash datatype. This would not only persist your hash across program runs, but across multiple machines. It's super fast, in memory, and you can have it up and running in < 5 minutes.

in IRB (assuming you've installed and are running `redis-server` and have installed redis-rb:

```
require "redis"
redis = Redis.new
```

The important operations are:

```
redis.hset(key, field, value)
```

and

```
redis.hget(key,field)
```